# Multiple Screenshots in Appium for Hybrid Apps

Tags: java, overriding, screenshot, appium

I have been using the screen capture[`public void getScreenshot(){...}`] in Appium for test failures and start. I would want to call the same method for every `findElement()` in my suite. I tried doing this :

Create a Custom Driver as :

```
public class CustomDriver extends AppiumDriver{
        public WebElement scrollToExact(String element) {   
            WebElement x = null;
            return x;
        }

        public WebElement scrollTo(String element){
            WebElement y = null;
            return y;
        }

        @Override
        public List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
            try {
                getScreenshot();
            }
            catch (IOException iox){
                System.out.println(iox.getMessage());
            }
            return by.findElements(this);
        }

        @Override
        public WebElement findElement(By by) {
            try {
                getScreenshot();
            } 
            catch(IOException iox){
                System.out.println(iox.getMessage());
            }
            return by.findElement(this);
        }
}
```

Used this driver to create the test suite.

*Q1. Though this worked fine for me but while I switch context to Webview, my driver would not respond finding the elements in that context. Anything wrong that I followed up here? [Would provide details if required,not sure by self.]*

*Q2. Is there anything simpler that I am missing to get screenshots for every `findElement()` call in my suite*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience screenshots work only in the NATIVE_APP context, so if you are in a WebView context you've got to switch to the native context and then switch back, something like:

```
    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
        String originalContext = getContext();
        if ("NATIVE_APP".equals(originalContext)) {
            originalContext = null; // no need to switch
        } else {
            context("NATIVE_APP");
        }
        try {
            getScreenshot(); // Before screenshot
            return super.findElements(by);
        } finally {                
            if (originalContext!=null) {
                context(originaContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: any specific reason to assign originalContext to null?

Comment: `@Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
        String originalContext = getContext();
        if (!originalContext.equals("NATIVE_APP")) {
         context("NATIVE_APP");
        }
        try {
            getScreenshot(); // Before screenshot
            return super.findElements(by);
        } finally {                
                context(originaContext);
            }
    }` does the trick for me

Comment: it is a way to indicate that there is no need to switch context back in finally. Alternatively it could be if (!"NATIVE_APP".equals(originalContext)) {
            context("NATIVE_APP");
        }
        try {
            getScreenshot(); // Before screenshot
            return super.findElements(by);
        } finally {                
            if (!"NATIVE_APP".equals(originalContext)) {
                context(originaContext);
            }
        } - a matter of coding preference.